# Let $f\left(x\right)=\left|x\right|^{\frac{5}{2}},x\in \mathbb R$, Which of the following statements are true

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f\left(x\right)=\left|x\right|^{\frac{5}{2}},x\in \mathbb R$, Which of the following statements are true

(a). The function $f$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$

(b). The function $f$ is differentiable everywhere and $f'(x) = \frac{5}{2}|x|^{\frac{5}{2}}$.

(c) The function $f$ is differentiable everywhere and $f'(x) = \frac{5}{2}|x|^{\frac{1}{2}}x$.

(a)We can easily prove that $\lim_h\to 0 \frac{|h|^{\frac{5}{2}}-0}{h-0}=\lim_h\to 0 \frac{|h||h|^{\frac{1}{2}}}{h}=0$. So, Derivative exists at $0$. I don't know how to differentiate it.

Comment: $|h|^{5/2}=|h|^2|h|^{1/2}=h^2|h|^{1/2}$, not $|h||h|^{1/2}$.

Comment: When you need a subscript or superscript with more than 1 key-stroke, enclose it in braces:  \lim_{h\to 0} yields $\lim_{h\to 0}$........ (c) is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying chain rule, $$f'(x) = \frac 52 |x|^{3/2} \frac d{dx} |x|$$

For $x$ not equal to $0$, $$\frac d{dx}|x| = \frac {x}{|x|} $$

So substituting, $$f'(x) = \frac 52 |x|^{1/2}x$$

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\frac{|h|^{5/2}}{h}$$. Let $$h>0$$ then we can simplify to $h^{1/2}$. If $h<0$ then we have
$$-\frac{(-h)^{5/2}}{-h}=-(-h)^{1/2}$$ Both values are not the same.

Comment: Answer in the key is given that (c).

Answer (score 0):

Let us compute the derivative of the function with the standard differentiation rules, and we get that $f'(x)$ equals

$\frac{5}{2}x^{\frac{3}{2}}$  for $x > 0$

and

$-\frac{5}{2}x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ for any $x < 0$.

In $x=0$ the derivative is equal in both cases (that is equivalent to differentiating from the right and from the left) and is $0$ itself.